# How to distinguish one field from another by iterating over the elements of Activity?

Tags: android, android-layout

In my Activity I have some text fields(EditText) for *names* and some fields for *telephone numbers*.
I have functions to get all elements of a part of Activity:

```
public static List<View> getAllChildren(View v) {
    ArrayList<View> resultViewList = getOneIfNotGroup(v);
    if (!resultViewList.isEmpty()) return resultViewList;

    ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) v;
    for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View child = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);

        // Get nested children
        List<View> childViewList = new ArrayList<View>();
        childViewList.add(v);
        childViewList.addAll(getAllChildren(child));

        resultViewList.addAll(childViewList);
    }

    return resultViewList;
}

private static List<View> getOneIfNotGroup(View v) {
    boolean notGroup = !(v instanceof ViewGroup);
    if (notGroup) {
        ArrayList<View> viewArrayList = new ArrayList<View>();
        viewArrayList.add(v);
        return viewArrayList;
    }
    return new ArrayList<>();
}
```

And function to filter this list by class:

```
public static<T> List<T> getFiltered(List<?> list, Class<T> myClass) {
    List<T> result = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (Object elem : list)
        if (myClass.isInstance(elem))
            result.add((T) elem);
    return result;
}
```

For example `List<EditText> fields = getFiltered(allElementsList, EditText.class);`
But in this case both *names* and *telephone numbers* fields will be in this list.

So, how can I make checking to get one type of them (names or numbers)? 
Perhaps there is some property (like CSS classes) that I can describe in xml and check in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "Tag" for distinguish between two `EditText` by following way

set some different text for different `EditText` like

```
edtName.setTag("name");
edtTelephone.setTag("tele");
edtXyz.setTag("xyz");
```

To use in layout

```
android:tag="name"
```

Make sure you are providing tags to each `EditText` you are using in layout.

Now, in your `getFiltered()` method, you can check which kind of tag it is like

```
public static<T> List<T> getFiltered(List<?> list, Class<T> myClass,String tag) {
    List<T> result = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (Object elem : list)
        if (myClass.isInstance(elem)){
            if(myClass.isInstance(EditText.class)){

                //Following is logic to check EditText with tag
                String edtTag = ((EditText)elem).getTag().toString();

                if(edtTag.equals(tag)){
                    result.add((T) elem);
                }

            }else {
                result.add((T) elem);
            }
        }
    return result;
}
```